# Angular Material how to build overlapping components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am very used to coding using angular material components. However, I need to build a screen that has :

1. a 'table with rows' in the background
2. cards, on top of table in fixed position and not floating, showing status of row elements
3. a scroll bar to scroll the cards.

What is the best approach to build a page that has this layout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem was finally solved using z-index. Z-Index in html page gives us ability to organize html as layers one on top/bottom of others. We implemented it as a table in the background with z-index of auto. Another html division was developed with z-index of 1 (this html contained the material cards that float on top of table in the background). Hope it helps someone who runs into this scenario.